# What is the typical weight distribution for a brushless motor?

Tags: motor, brushless-motor

Brushless motors, like regular motors, have different parts (commutator, stater, etc).
What do these various parts weigh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took apart a [Turnigy D2836](https://hobbyking.com/en_us/turnigy-d2836-8-1100kv-brushless-outrunner-motor.html) brushless DC motor. Despite the weight listed on the website, the actual weight of the motor *without the mounting equipment* is **54 Grams**.

Here is the breakdown

- Magnets: 9 grams, 16.7%
- Bottom Can: 6 grams, 11.1%
- Top Can: 4.5 grams, 8.33%
- Main Axle: 1.5 grams, 2.78%
- Middle can: 9 grams, 16.7%
- Coils: 6 grams, 11.1%
- Leads & plugs: 4 grams, 7.41%
- Ferrite core: 14 grams, 25.93%

This motor is an out-runner, so the bottom can and the ferrite core have a ball bearing that is included in the weight, but I did not measure it separately. This can be used as a guide for other motors.